# Recognize the type of the parameters of a user defined sql to be used in a Delphi TQuery at runtime

Tags: delphi, parameterized-query, bde

I'm writing a delphi(7 ver) application and in some place I want to execute parameterized queries (for BDE and Paradox) which will be loaded at runtime into a TQuery by the user. These queries will be stored in text files (one text file for one query). The application then, will construct for any parameter of the query, one input control (Tedit) in order to be able to accept values by the user. Also there will be a button for the execution of query. My question is how can  I recognize the datatype of the query's parameter?  Is there a way to get this type without of cause to be included in some way in the text file containing the query?

Comment: Generally, you would `Prepare` the query and then iterate through its `Params` and check the just iterated parameter's `DataType`. But I have no clue if `TQuery` can parse the query, and from the underlying table metadata determine the column's data type (trying to forget my frustration from BDE).

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I see there is not information on Tquery about the datatype of it's parameters after the preparation.

Comment: BDE and Paradox are not good start for an app nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a second query from the first, but modify its `where` clause to ensure no rows.

   SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE PKFIELD IS NULL
2. Name your parameters so that you can establish their datatypes from the fieldtypes of this second query.

I realise this only works for relatively simple cases, but it should get you some of the way.

Comment: Thank you, Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

the advantage of using a parameter is that you don't need to know its data type. 
Use the string value from the tedit
"select * from mytable where myfield = :param1"
"parambyname('param1').asstring := edit1.text"

Answer (score -1):

I've made this with MySQL database. you must define some parameters, Exemple:
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyField=[ANNEE];
in this case, i have an other table, called balise, that look like this

"ID"    "BALISE"    "CAPTION"   "DEFAULT_VALUE" "CNDT"  "COMPOSANT"
"1" "ANNEE" "Année" "2014"  "Properties.MaxValue=2014||Properties.MinValue=2007"    1;

in runtime, this mean that:
Make in my Panel, a TLablel that have caption Année
Make in the same line an other component type 1 (That mean in my case TcxSpinEdit), this component have défault value 2014, have Two properties Max Value=2014 and Min Value=2007, (I use RTTI to modifie this value of parameters, in Delphi ver7, use TypeInfo).

An Other Button with function called Actualise, this function have Original query, must browse an array of TBalise that i have created, take the value (In my case, take TcxSpinEdit(MyObject).Value), and replace it in the copy of my query (AnsiReplaceStr(Requete, '[ANNEE]', MyValue)), so i have the final query to execute it.

I have module in complete projet, worked with this methode, and it workk fine.